# sql count consecutive periods on a day

Tags: azure-sql-database

Given the following table

```
ID  Teacher     lessondate              period  Group   Course  Room    Lnr     Count
167 teacher 1   2013-12-02 08:30:00.000 1       group 1 NE      room 1  223     1
168 teacher 1   2013-12-02 09:15:00.000 2       group 1 NE      room 1  224     1
169 teacher 1   2013-12-02 10:00:00.000 3       group 1 ENG     room 1  226     1
170 teacher 1   2013-12-02 11:00:00.000 4       group 1 VAKT    room 1  228     1
171 teacher 1   2013-12-02 11:45:00.000 5       group 1 DGV     room 1  227     1
172 teacher 1   2013-12-02 13:00:00.000 6       group 1 VAKT    room 1  228     1
183 teacher 1   2013-12-05 08:30:00.000 1       group 1 VAKT    room 2  228     1
184 teacher 1   2013-12-05 09:15:00.000 2       group 1 NE      room 2  223     2
185 teacher 1   2013-12-05 10:00:00.000 3       group 1 NE      room 2  223     2
186 teacher 1   2013-12-05 11:00:00.000 4       group 1 LB      room 1  222     2
187 teacher 1   2013-12-05 11:45:00.000 5       group 1 LB      room 1  222     2
188 teacher 1   2013-12-05 13:00:00.000 6       group 1 REK     room 1  225     1
189 teacher 1   2013-12-06 14:45:00.000 8       group 2 AAA             4       3
190 teacher 1   2013-12-06 15:30:00.000 9       group 2 AAA             4       3
191 teacher 1   2013-12-06 16:15:00.000 10      group 2 AAA             4       3
```

I would like to generate the count column in SQL with the following conditions:

the count is > 1 if the periods are on the same day AND consecutive (on period) AND the lesson number (lnr) is equal.

Explanation of the data:

- 167 and 168: same day, consecutive period, lesson number not equal=>count=1
- 170 and 172: same day, same lesson number, period not consecutive=>count=1
- 184 and 185: same day, same lesson number, consecutive period=>count=2,
- 189,190,191: same day, same lesson number, consecutive period=>count=3

I guess its something with partition, over , etc, but my sql knowledge lacks in that part :(

**EDIT:**The query I got so far:

```
select distinct  a.*, blockHours 
from timetablerecords a 
join (
select distinct lessonnumber, convert(date,c.lessonDate) ld, count(distinct period) blockHours 
from timetablerecords c 
where teacher='teacher 1' 
group by  convert(date,c.lessonDate), c.lessonnumber, c.course 
) b 
on a.lessonNumber=b.lessonnumber and convert(date,a.lessonDate)= b.ld
where teacher='teacher 1' 
order by lessondate,period
```

This does not take into account inconsecutive (or is it unconsecutive?) periods. With the data above it returns count=2 for id's 170 and 172

The query is run on a MS SQL Azure database
The output should contain all columns mentioned in the table. Only column not shown above but which should also be in result is 'duration'
The table could be created with the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[timetablerecords](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [teacher] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [lessonDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [period] [int] NOT NULL,
    [group] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [course] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [room] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [lessonNumber] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [lessonDuration] [int] NOT NULL,
    [locationCode] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Well, what have you got so far?  This will help explain some of your logic, and tell us what columns you need.  Also, please include an actual 'results table', with the output you want.  What 'flavor' of SQL, especially as windowing functions (of which `PARTITION BY` is a part) are _not_ universally supported.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: there are only very few DBMS left that do not support window functions.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I've edit the question, added the qeury I've got sofar and described the table

Comment: Okay, and desired results?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: desired result = table with columns mentioned ammended with count column (id, teacher, lessondate, period,[group],course,room,lessonnumber,lessonduration, locationcode, [count]) I named the count 'blockHours')

Comment: .... No, you have a source table; construct a results table along the same lines.  Don't just describe your desired results, actually set them up.  Like if you were doing automated testing - most tools won't take "Oh, put these columns together, and add these up" (if you did, you'd have _two_ pieces of code to check) - you have to give the expected layout and contents.  It's also a good way for you to verify what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I don't understand what you mean. My source table is the table as described in the create script (so without the 'count' column. My desired result is the same table bit WITH the computed 'count' column

Comment: Okay, wow, I'm dense.  I get it now, thanks.